# How the actor use the output from the critic to make action in actor-critic network?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic-methods

I am reading about the actor-critic architecture. I am confused about how the actor determines the action using the value (or future reward) from the critic network.

Below you have the most popular picture of actor-critic network.

[image: Actor Critic Network]

It looks like the input of the actor network is only the "state" variable ($s_t$), it has nothing to do with the critic network.

However, from the equation below

[image: Policy Gradient with Critic Network]

the actor seems to be related to critic network.

I have a few questions

1. Does actor network has two inputs, state variable and future reward (output from critic network), or only the state variable?
2. If the actor network does take future reward as input, how does it use it? Only during the training stage, or in the action making stage?
3. Is there a "policy iteration" procedure happens during decision making stage, i.e. for every state $s_t$, policy network will make several attempts with critic network, and output the best policy?

Comment: "It looks like the input of the actor network is only the "state" variable (), it has nothing to do with the critic network.". Note that the picture contains an arrow from the critic which crosses the the actor.

Comment: Where did you find that equation? Can you please links us to the source of that equation?

Comment: @nbro I thought that is the TD error feed back for retrain the policy network and critic network.

Comment: it is from https://www.slideshare.net/zhihua98/actor-critic-algorithm in page 11